# Drupal CCK field select option names, where are they?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a custom content type which has a field called "location" which is a long select list (100 or so items).  I want to get an array of all locations which have a piece of content associated with them.  The numeric value of this field is stored in content_type_[my_content_type], but I can't find anywhere in the database where the name of the values are stored.  I hope that's not too confusing - just to be clear, I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field_location_value) FROM content_type_[my_content_type]
```

and then

```
SELECT field_location_name_or_something FROM where_on_earth_are_the_names_stored
```

and then do something with the two arrays to find the names I want.

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot.  Drupal 6, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you mean select list field of CCK**:
Get all location associated with current node (piece of content?):

```
$node = node_load('YOUR content ID');
print_r($node->field_location); // $node->field_location - this will array of values.
```

Get all values of that field (defined in "Allowed values"):

```
  $content_field = content_fields('field_location');
  $allowed_values = content_allowed_values($content_field); // array of values
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking for the allowed values.  Out of curiosity, though, do you have any idea where in the database this information is stored?

Answer (score 1):

I found this, after much trial and tribulation, in the database table `content_node_field_instance`, under the field's widget settings field.

Answer (score 0):

This Drupal 6 code snipped will retrieve your cck field value options and put them in the $allowed_values variable as an array. Replace 'YOUR_CCK_FIELD_NAME' with your cck field name (name, not label)


`$cck_field_name = 'YOUR_CCK_FIELD_NAME';

$cck_field = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT global_settings FROM {content_node_field} WHERE field_name = '%s'", $cck_field_name));

$cck_field_global_settings = unserialize($cck_field->global_settings);

$allowed_values = explode("\r\n", trim($cck_field_global_settings['allowed_values'], "\r\n"));`

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 if you have a field of type List (text) then I have written the following function to return an array of options:

```
function get_drupal_select_options($field_name) {
    $options = unserialize(db_query("SELECT c.data
                FROM field_config_instance i
                INNER JOIN field_config c ON c.id = i.field_id
                WHERE i.field_name = :fieldname", array(':fieldname'=>$field_name))->fetchField());
    return $options['settings']['allowed_values'];
}
```